# Tkinter Pillow Resize Image Looks Choppy While Resizing

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have a frame that stores a label which stores a background image. When I resize the form and the frame resizes, the background image of the label looks really choppy while it's being resized by the function. I was thinking about putting the function on a separate thread because I believe the image might look choppy because of it being on the main thread.

Here's what I've tried:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, Frame
from tkinter import ttk, PhotoImage
import threading
import time
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

#create groupbox1 background image for modern look framing
    self.gb1_img = Image.open('imgs/groupbox-1.png')
    self.gb1_img = self.gb1_img.resize((260, 490), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
    self.gb1_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.gb1_img)

    self.gb1_container = Frame(self, bg='#333333', width=280)
    self.gb1_container.pack(side='left', fill='y', padx=20, pady=(120, 20))
    self.gb1_container.bind('<Configure>', self.start_resize_gb1)

    self.gb1 = Label(self.gb1_container, image=self.gb1_img, bg='#333333')
    self.gb1.place(x=0, y=0)


def start_resize_gb1(self, e):
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.resize_gb1, args=(e,), daemon=1)
    t.start()


#resize groupbox1 frame image
    def resize_gb1(self, e):
        self.gb1_img1 = Image.open('imgs/groupbox-1.png')
        self.gb1_img1 = self.gb1_img1.resize((e.width, e.height), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        self.gb1_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.gb1_img1)
        self.gb1.configure(image=self.gb1_img1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainWindow()
    app.title('Main Window')
    app.configure(bg='#333333')

    #center the Main Window:
    w = 1000  # Width
    h = 620  # Height

    app.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    app.mainloop()
```

Is there a way that I can bind the function on it's own thread so that it doesn't look so choppy while resizing?

The error that I keep getting is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-57 (resize_gb1):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\Python\Project1\testing\MAIN.py", line 92, in resize_gb1
    self.gb1_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.gb1_img1)
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.paste(image)
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 195, in paste
    im.load()
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 268, in load
    self.load_end()
  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 962, in load_end
    self.fp.read(4)  # CRC
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Indentation isn't correct.

Comment: Actually it is correct back in the actual project. I just copied and pasted the parts needed from the project to shorten it, that's when the indentation is out of alignment here. It's fine in the actual project. I just need help with the concept of the threading implementation.

Comment: @toyota Supra That's definitely not the problem.